# Twitter tweet button - tweet event not firing

Tags: twitter, tweets

using following script, tweet window opens up but tweet event is not getting called. How can I bind

```
window.open to tweet window:

       var TWTShare = function() {
       var title = metadata.title,
       url = metadata.url,
       text = metadata.text,
       href = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url="+encodeURIComponent(url)+"&title="+encodeURIComponent(title)+"&text="+encodeURIComponent(text);


window.open(href, 'share it on twitter', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, copyhistory=no, width='+width+', height='+height+', top='+top+', left='+left);

        }

twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {           
        console.log('tweet');           

    });
```

Comment: I have same problem ... if you have figured it out then please let me know